# Jest - ReferenceError: define is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to use jest to start doing some unit testing but I've come across this error that a lot of people seem to be getting but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's is what I'm trying to do (and I realize requirejs isn't supported):

```
jest.mock("../widgets/", () => {
  return <button>button</button>;
});

describe('TextInput', () => {
  describe('when user inputs a value', () => {
    it('calls correct function to handle change', () => {
      const handleChange = jest.fn();
      const value = "test"
      const wrapper = shallow(<TextInput handleChange={handleChange} />);
      const textInputElement = wrapper.find("#textfield");
      textInputElement.simulate('change', {target: { value }})

      expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as TestUtils from "react-dom/test-utils";
import { TextInput } from "../widgets/";
```

and here is my `package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [

    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/src/**/?(*.)+(test).js"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js)$": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "./config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "./config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ]
 }
```

Upon running jest, I get the error `ReferenceError: define is not defined` and here is a more detailed error:
[image: errorMsg]

I would appreciate any help! Been pulling my hair out over this for the past few days :-(

Comment: uhhhh your first codeblock is super weird... are those imports actually **below** your test like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: Just realized that according to docs `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` should in fact also work. Anyway you could give `mock.calls.length` a try.

---

As far as I know assertions on jest function mocks do not work like this

```
expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

You should give this a try

```
expect(handleChange.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

As described in the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-property)